# Integral extension and s.o.p.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

> Let $R\subset S$ be an integral extension. Is a system of parameters of $R$ a system of parameters of $S$?

I think so, since there is good behavior in dimensions.

Many thanks.

Comment: What is a system of parameter R? Could you please define it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose $R$ and $S$ are local rings with maximal ideals $\mathfrak m$, respectively $\mathfrak n$.
If $r_1,\dots,r_n$ is a sop for $R$, then the ideal $(r_1,\dots,r_n)$ is $\mathfrak m$-primary. We wonder if $(r_1,\dots,r_n)S$ is $\mathfrak n$-primary. First note that $\sqrt{(r_1,\dots,r_n)S}=\sqrt{\mathfrak mS}$. But $\mathfrak mS$ is $\mathfrak n$-primary since $\sqrt{\mathfrak mS}=\mathfrak n$ (why?). So $r_1,\dots,r_n$ is a sop for $S$.